# Parallax div without a background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

Working on a parallax effect for a site. I've gotten the parallax effect to function properly using a background image but I've decided to change things up just a bit. Rather than using a bg image for the effect I was looking to apply the effect to an entire div but I can't seem to get this working using the entire div. Looking to apply the effect to everything inside the .section div while keeping the #subpanel / scroll-pane independently scrollable.

html -

```
<div class="col col-100">
<div class="col col-30">
<div class="section">    
<div id="subpanel" class="nav_dialog displayed" style="height: 660px; left: ; display: block;">
<div class="close_link">
    <a href="#">Close (x)</a>
</div>
<div class="scroll-pane" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 475px;">
<div class="jspContainer" style="width: 475px; height: 620px;">
    <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px 65px 0px 20px; top: 0px; width: 396px; font-size: 15px;">
        <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5uxqi0mgl/cats1.jpg" alt="">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="jspVerticalBar">
        <div class="jspCap jspCapTop"></div>
        <div class="jspTrack">
            <div class="jspDrag">
                <div class="jspDragTop"></div>
                <div class="jspDragBottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jspCap jspCapBottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS -

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $.fn.parallax = function(options){
        var $$ = $(this);
        offset = $$.offset();
        var defaults = {
            "start": 0,
            "stop": offset.top + $$.height(),
            "coeff": 0.95
        };
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function(){
            $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();  
                if((windowTop >= opts.start) && (windowTop <= opts.stop)) {
                    newCoord = windowTop * opts.coeff;
                    //console.log($$)

                    $$.css({
                        "position": "0 "+ newCoord + "px"
                    });
                } 
            });
        });
    };    
    $('.section').parallax({ "coeff":-0.65 });
    $('.section .scroll-pane').parallax({ "coeff":2.55 });

})
</script>

<script>
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

Hopefully that makes some sense. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This was an excellent question!  This was the only question I was able to find regarding parallax without background images.  Your JS here is brilliant and very helpful

Answer (score 0):

it seems you changed **background-position** to **position**. 
Allowed values for position are absolute,fixed,relative,static & inherit

You are probably looking for something like this to move a complete div

```
$$.css({
    "top": newCoord + "px"
});
```

or

```
$$.css({
    "margin-top": newCoord + "px"
});
```